# How to get and use the value returned by a stored procedure to a INSERT INTO... SELECT... statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am just new in SQL language and still studying it. I'm having hard time looking for answer on how can I use the stored procedure and insert value into a table.

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestID
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewID VARCHAR(30),
            @GenID INT,
            @BrgyCode VARCHAR(5) = '23548'

    SET @GenID = (SELECT TOP (1) NextID 
                  FROM dbo.RandomIDs 
                  WHERE IsUsed = 0 
                  ORDER BY RowNumber)
     SET @NewID = @BrgyCode + '-' + CAST(@GenID AS VARCHAR (30))

     UPDATE dbo.RandomIDs 
     SET dbo.RandomIDs.IsUsed = 1
     WHERE dbo.RandomIDs.NextID = @GenID

     SELECT @NewID
 END;
```

and what I'm trying to do is this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Residents([ResidentID], NewResidentID, [ResLogdate],
 ...
    SELECT
        [ResidentID],
        EXEC TestID ,
        [ResLogdate],
        ....
    FROM 
        source.dbo.Resident;
```

There is a table `dbo.RandomIDs` containing random 6 digit non repeating numbers where I'm pulling out the value via the stored procedure and updating the `IsUsed` column of the table to 1. I'm transferring data from one database to another database and doing some processing on the data while transferring. Part of the processing is generating a new ID with the required format.

But I can't get it to work Sad I've been searching the net for hours now but I'm not getting the information that I need and that the reason for my writing. I hope someone could help me with this.

Thanks,
Darren

Comment: You cannot use a stored procedure like this - if you really want to use a value inside your `SELECT` statement, then it would have to be a stored **function** - not a stored procedure. Or you could execute the stored procedure before your `INSERT` and store the value returned by it into a SQL Server variable, and then use that in your `SELECT` statemnet

Comment: Thank you marc_s for enlightening me. I already tried to use a function but I found out that it is not capable of updating a table (dbo.RandomIDs) within it.

Answer (score 0):

your question is little bit confusing, because you have not explained what you want to do. As i got your question, you want to fetch random id from randomids table and after performed some processing on nextid you want to insert it into resident table [newresidentid] and end of the procedure you fetch data from resident table. if i get anything wrong feel free to ask me.

your procedure solution is following.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [TestId]
      AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN

DECLARE @NEWID NVARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @GENID BIGINT
DECLARE @BRGYCODE VARCHAR(5) = '23548'
DECLARE @COUNT INTEGER
DECLARE @ERR NVARCHAR(20) = 'NO IDS IN RANDOM ID'

SET @COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(NEXTID) FROM RandomIds WHERE [IsUsed] = 0)
SET @GENID = (SELECT TOP(1) [NEXTID] FROM RandomIds WHERE [IsUsed] = 0 ORDER BY [ID] ASC)
--SELECT @GENID AS ID 

IF @COUNT = 0
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @ERR AS ERROR
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN 
        SET @NEWID = @BRGYCODE + '-' + CAST(@GENID AS varchar(30))

        UPDATE RandomIds SET [IsUsed] = 1 WHERE [NextId] = @GENID 

        INSERT INTO Residents ([NewResidentId] , [ResLogDate] ) VALUES (@NEWID , GETDATE())

        SELECT * FROM Residents
    END
END
```

this procedure will fetch data from your randomids table and perform some processing on nextid than after it directs insert it into resident table and if you want to insert some data through user you can use parameter after declaring procedure name

E.G

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [TESTID] 
     @PARAM1 DATATYPE, 
     @PARAM2 DATATYPE
 AS
 BEGIN 

 END
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Nayan. Sorry for the confusion. Basically what I was wanting to have is to create a Stored Procedure with these tasks:

Comment: I don't think this will work with multiple simultaneous calls.  COUNT and WHERE will be looking at committed work, not in-flight transactions. Mind you, the whole requirement is odd.

Comment: @LoztInSpace user can use having clause in aggregate function instead of where condition

Comment: @DJVillareal solution is okay or not?

Comment: @LoztInSpace previous comment was mistake,count and where i have used for additional feature in order to stop null entry in ID list else user can remove that statement if he/she knows about random id number

Comment: It's not a mistake.  Your GENID code will not work with two concurrent transactions.

Comment: @LoztInSpace chance of concurrent transaction is less because it works in milliseconds

Comment: Even if you do know the scope and duration of the transaction  (which I assume you don't) there are proper solutions to this. "chance of X is low" != "a proper solution"

Comment: @LoztInSpace okay will update new answer as per duration and scope of the transaction

Comment: @LoztInSpace is use of transaction can remove problem of concurrent call on SP? because with each transaction opens on new connection and transaction scope is on connection

Comment: Hi @Nayan. Sorry I fell asleep. I haven't tested your proposed answer yet but at least I know that using a stored procedure inside a select statement as what marc_s said will not work. I'll try your suggestion in a while.

Comment: @Nayan use of transactions will not remove the problem. If anything it will make it worse as it will extend the time available for conflict. As it happens, in this case it doesn't matter anyway as it's a one-off migration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that your requirement is a good one but here is a way to do it.

Bear in mind that concurrent sessions will not be able to read your update until it is committed so you have to kind of "lock" the update so you will get a block until you're going to commit or rollback.  This is rubbish for concurrency, but that's a side effect of this requirement.

```
declare @cap table ( capturedValue int);
declare @GENID  int;

update top (1) RandomIds   set IsUsed=1 
output inserted.NextID into @cap
where IsUsed=0;

set @GENID =(select max( capturedValue) from @cap )
```

A better way would be to use an IDENTITY or SEQUENCE to solve your problem.  This would leave gaps but help concurrency.

Comment: Thank for giving me another option. This is just a one time process I need to do that will be applied only during the migration of data. The data is currently residing in MS Access that will be migrated and recoded for SQL Server. I could have used IDENTITY or SEQUENCE but there's a requirement in the format for the NewResidentId field aside from it should not be sequential.

Comment: Migration is different and you can use different techniques to OLTP. I still don't agree with the requirement for random, non-sequential values. Something smells here, but not my circus, not my monkeys :)

Comment: _"Something smells here, but not my circus, not my monkeys "_

I do not know what you mean by this but there are reasons why there's a need to make a random non-sequential value. One example is when you need to do some research and you need to use a hospital patient database. To protect the identity of the patient, you will not be given the patient ID but random non-sequential numbers instead. But anyway, I still thank you for taking time sharing your thoughts.